# indicator-applet-appmenu missing menu items

Tags: 14.04, gnome, indicator, menu, appmenu

Sometimes, when using any program, and the menu items are refreshed, indicator-applet-appmenu will lose some of the menu items, place items in the wrong menu, not label the menu, or all three.
This happens most often when using Sublime Text and LibreOffice.

I have checked the log in ~/.cache/indicator-applet-appmenu.log and found that it gives an error whenever I find there is a missing menu item.

```
DEBUG: Indicator-Applet-Appmenu - Signal: Entry Added from libappmenu.so
WARNING: Gtk - gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkModelMenuItem
WARNING: Indicator-Appmenu - Unable to find entry: 0x1bc9250
DEBUG: Indicator-Applet-Appmenu - Signal: Entry Added from libappmenu.so
WARNING: Gtk - gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkModelMenuItem
WARNING: Indicator-Appmenu - Unable to find entry: 0x1bc9250
CRITICAL: Gtk - gtk_label_set_text_with_mnemonic: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
CRITICAL: Gtk - gtk_label_set_text_with_mnemonic: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
CRITICAL: Gtk - gtk_label_set_text_with_mnemonic: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
```

Im using ubuntu 14.04.1LTS on 3.13.0-24-generic

indicator-applet-appmenu is at 12.10.2, but when I click on the about option, it says 12.10.1